# Serialize JSON string SBJSON vs NSJSONSerialization vs anything else?

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization, sbjson

I am receiving this JSON string and want to know how to serialize it into a dictionary so that I can parse it into a managed object.

I have looked at a few ways (named in the title), and can't seem to find the simplest, quickest alternative. I would like to use NSJSONSerialization, but I'm not sure it is made to do this?

Code where string comes in

```
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"String %@",data);
```

NSLog message

```
String [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"re ee","name":"re ee","2":"http:\/\/ree.com\/images\/re.png","backgroundImageUrl":"http:\/\/ree.com\/images\/re.png","3":"http:\/\/ree.com\/images\/re.png","logoImageUrl":"http:\/\/ree.com\/images\/re.png"}]<br />
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Both are reasonably solid.  (Truth be told, SBJSON has more "burn in" time, but NSJSONSerialization has Apple behind it.)  In part it simply has to do with which is more convenient.  With SBJSON you work with NSStrings, while with NSJSONSerialization you work with NSData, plus a few minor operational differences.  I wouldn't bother with any of the others.

Comment: So I'm using AFNetworking which apparently uses NSStrings?

Comment: Well, in your above example `response` is NSData, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

[JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) is what your are looking for.

Besides the ease of use, it's quicker than SBJSon, even quicker than NSJSONSerialization.

For your example, your can get an array like this:

```
NSArray* arrayFromJson = [data objectFromJSONString];
NSString* id = arrayFromJson[0][@"id"]；
```

Easy, huh?

Comment: NSJSONSerialization is perfectly fine. JSONKit has a potential issue - due to its use of deprecated functions. It's not that much faster than NSJSONSerialization anymore since the Apples parser became faster.

Comment: Can anyone provide any insight on how the parsing speeds are now? Last update of the `Readme.md` on GitHub is 2 years old. I wonder how things are now.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization all the way